# Trying to perform a method on a params in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I want to write a method that loops through all the params to make sure they aren't all blank.

My params are:

```
params[:search][:company]
params[:search][:phone]
params[:search][:city]
params[:search][:state]
params[:search][:email]
```

I have this method:

```
def all_blank_check(params)
  array=[]

  params[:search].each do |key, value|
    array << value unless value.blank?
  end

  if array.count < 1
      return true
  else
     return false
  end
end
```

But when I try something like `all_blank_check(params)` I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `all_blank_check' for #<Class:0x108c08830>):
```

Do I need to convert the params to an array first?  Can't I perform a method on params?

Edit - full source:

```
        def index
          @customers = Customer.search_search(params)
        end
```

`def self.search_search(params)
      search_field = []
      search_values = []
      array = []
      test = ''    

      if !params[:search].nil? && all_blank_check(params[:search]


              if !params[:search].nil? && !params[:search][:company].blank?
              search_field << 'customers.company LIKE ?'
              search_values << "%#{params[:search][:company]}%"

              end

              if !params[:search].nil? && !params[:search][:city].blank?
              search_field << 'customers.city = ?'
              search_values << "#{params[:search][:city]}"
              end

              if !params[:search].nil? && !params[:search][:phone].blank?
              search_field << 'customers.phone_1 = ?'
              search_values << "%#{params[:search][:phone]}%"
              end

            conditions = [search_field.join(' AND ')] + search_values

            Customer.where(conditions).includes(:customer_contacts).limit(10)
        end
    end


    def all_blank_check(params)
        params[:search].each do |key, value|
          array << value unless value.blank?
        end

        if array.count < 1
            return false
          end
          if array.count > 1
            return true
        end
    end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the type of `params`, the problem is that the method `all_blank_check` does not exist on the object you call it on.

You defined it as an instance method and you're trying to call it from the class method `search_param`, which won't work.

If you want to make `all_blank_check` a class method you need to change the definition to `def self.all_blank_check(params)` - same as `search_param`.

Comment: AWESOME!  I thought Class methods where only for searches (Customer.find) , I really learned something today, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use more Ruby-minded code like this:

```
def self.all_blank?(params)
   params[:search].count{|key, value| !value.blank?} == 0
end
```

This counts the values that are not blank; if the number is 0, it means all are blank.
It avoids creating a new array just for counting.

Comment: Or even better `params[:search].values.all?(&:blank?)`